# Is a caching layer needed when using a nosql data store?

Tags: caching, nosql, redis, couchbase, riak

Do we really need a caching layer when using a nosql datastore? I understand the use case when using a traditional sql db, the overhead of query processing can be avoided by a simple key/value lookup. But in the case of nosql, that's not the case anymore. Also, the cache instances are almost always running in separate instances, which means they still have the same network delay associated with accessing a nosql datastore.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is "It depends on the NoSQL database and how it's configured.". As-is your question is too broad as it would require an entire rundown of every NoSQL solution and how it works (some depending on specific configurations). In some cases, yes, in others, no.

Answer (score 1):

Caching is simply a tool for performance optimization and should be treated as such. This means doing some load testing to see what gains (if any) your performance enhancements give.

Most NoSQL servers do make claims to be much faster than traditional RDBMS but only testing it out will tell you if they're faster for your applications and infrastructure.